# TStringList's Object change automatically

Tags: delphi

I am created two stringList BookmarkedFields and BookmarkedRecord

`BookmarkedFields` it contains column name of the dataset
`BookmarkedRecord` it like `field:fieldValue`
  field is column name from BookmarkedFields
  fieldValue is value according to column

Here is procedure to stored the record in the stringList as column and column's value for record.

```
procedure TBkmrgString.GetIQBookmark(ADataset: TDataset);
var
  I : integer;
begin
  ADataset.GetFieldNames(BookmarkedFields);
  for I := 0 to BookmarkedFields.Count - 1 do
  begin
    BookmarkedRecord.AddObject(BookmarkedFields[I], ADataset.FieldByName(BookmarkedFields[I]));
  end;
end;
```

I try to find that record already stored in stringlist into the dataset.
But when start locating into dataset the value in stringlist automatically gets change and it shows the value which is pointed in dataset.
Object of stringlist which is automatically get changed.

```
procedure TBkmrgString.GotoIQBookmark(ADataset: TDataset);
var
 I : Integer;
 a : string;
begin
  ADataset.DisableControls;
  ADataset.First;
  while not ADataset.Eof do
  begin
    I := 0;
    while (I < BookmarkedFields.Count) and
          (ADataset.FieldByName(BookmarkedFields[ I ]).Value =  TField(BookmarkedRecord.Objects[ I ]).Value) do
    begin
      I := I + 1;
    end;
    if I = BookmarkedFields.Count then
      Break
    else
      ADataset.Next;
  end;
  ADataset.EnableControls;
end;
```

How to tackle from this situation, How did I persists the value in stringlist that stored, Don't want to be automatically changed object of stringlist.

Comment: Leaving aside your specific q, why on earth are you trying to locate the record in such an inefficient way, i.e. looping through all the records in dataset?  Why aren't you using ADataSet.Locate()?  See the online help for usage.

Comment: For the Locate needs a keyfield and I am using different dataset which having different column names and some of them are `View`and if I am using `Bookmark` after closing and reopening the dataset bookmark gets invalid  so That's why I am try to locate manualy.

Answer (score 2):

You are not storing field value in stringlist. This code

```pascal
BookmarkedRecord.AddObject(BookmarkedFields[I], ADataset.FieldByName(BookmarkedFields[I]));
```

adds `TField` object to `TStringList`. Field, not record. TField object is not storing value. It points to field, and every time you call it, value of current record in dataset will be returned. Not "remembered", only current.

If you need to remember value, you can do something like this:

```
BookmarkedRecord.AddObject(BookmarkedFields[I], TObject(ADataset.FieldByName(BookmarkedFields[I]).AsInteger));
```

This example is applicable for integer field.

Comment: This is right, but at the same time potentially dangerously misleading. It really needs a big fat warning *not* to simply change `AsInteger` to `AsString` for a string field.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a StringList containing one or more entries like this

> FieldNameN=FieldValueN

Obviously, this is much simpler than using two separate TStringLists.  Then, the following code will locate the dataset record
matching these fieldname/value pairs.  It uses four utility functions to convert
the contents of the StringList into the arguments to be passed the the dataset's
Locate function.  These utility functions are quite lengthy but useful additions to a general purpose toolbox. `HeadOf` and `TailOf` are useful for parsing Name/Value pairs. `MakeFieldNameList' and`MakeFieldValueList`are useful for constructing the arguments to be passed to`TDataSet.Locate`.

```
function LocateUsingStrings(ADataSet : TDataSet; Strings : TStrings) : Boolean;
var
  FieldNames : String;
  FieldValues : Variant;
begin
  FieldNames := MakeFieldNameList(Strings);
  FieldValues := MakeFieldValueList(Strings);
  Result := ADataSet.Locate(FieldNames, FieldValues, []);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if LocateUsingStrings(MyDataSet, Memo1.Lines) then
    Caption := 'found'
  else
    Caption := 'Not found';
end;
```

The utility functions are

```
function HeadOf(const Input : String; const Delim : String) : String;
//  With Input 'Name=Value', returns Name
var
  P     : integer;
begin
  P := Pos(Delim, Input);
  if P > 0 then
    Result := Copy(Input, 1, Pred(P))
  else
    Result := Input;
end;

function TailOf(const Input : String; const Delim : String) : String;
//  With Input 'Name=Value', returns Value
var
  P1,
  P2,
  Len : Integer;
begin
  P2 := MaxInt;
  Len := Length(Input);
  P1 := Pos(Delim, Input);
  if P1 > 0 then begin
    P2 := P1 + Length(Delim);
    if P2 <= Len then
      Result := Copy(Input, P2, Len)
    else
      Result := Input;
  end
  else
    Result := '';
end;

function MakeFieldNameList(Strings : TStrings) : String;
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  // Trim off leading and trailing blank lines
  Strings.Text := Trim(Strings.Text);

  Result := '';
  for i := 0 to Strings.Count - 1 do begin
    if Result <> '' then
      Result := Result + ';';
    Result := Result + HeadOf(Strings[i], '=');
  end;
end;

function MakeFieldValueList(Strings : TStrings) : Variant;
var
  i : Integer;
  Value : String;
begin
  // Trim off leading and trailing blank lines
  Strings.Text := Trim(Strings.Text);

  if Strings.Count = 1 then begin
    Value := TailOf(Strings[0], '=');
    Result := Value;
  end
  else begin
    Result := VarArrayCreate([0, Strings.Count -1], varVariant);
    for i := 0 to Strings.Count - 1 do begin
      Value := TailOf(Strings[i], '=');
      Result[i] := Value;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

If you really *must* encode your field values as Objects in your StringList, the code could readily be adapted to that.

Btw, the `MakeFieldNameList`, `MakeFieldValueList` and `LocateUsingStrings` functions have a TStrings input parameter rather than a TStringList one so that they aren't restricted to TStringlists.

Btw, Locate does **not** in general require keyfields, if you mean fields in
an index on the table.

Comment: This is an information which is very helpful for me and looks it should have to be worked, but I already tried different solution and it is works for me, I did the with one `stringlist` which is containing column names and associated values with that column  for the record put into in a `array of variant` that makes simplify to locate the record.